# validate confirmed password?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to validate the password field using javascript. Making sure when the user retypes the password in the confirm password field, it should be the same.

here is what i tried to do. This is the form. The onsubmit = "validate_reg()" is another validation using javascript to make sure all the fields must be filled.

```
<form name="register" action="signup.php" onsubmit="return validate_reg()"enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
<table width="600" border="0">
<tr><td width="210" height="45">Username*:</td><td>
<input type="text" size="40" name="userUsername" id="user_username" /></td></tr>
<tr><td width="210" height="45">Password*:</td><td>
<input type="password" size="40" name="userPassword" id="user_password"/></td></tr> 
    <tr><td width="210" height="45">Re-type Password:</td><td>
<input type="password" size="40" name="userPasswordConfirm" 
     id="user_password_confirm"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

This is the javascript codes:

```
<!--================Javascript for the validation of the Password Confirmation==========================-->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function validatepw() {
  if ( document.register.user_password.value != document.register.user_password_confirm.value)
    {
    alert('Passwords did not match!');
        return false;
        }else{
        document.register.submit();
        return true;
    }
    }
</script>

<!--================Javascript for the validation of the required fields ================================-->
<script type="text/javascript">

    function validate_reg()
    {
    var isValid = true;

    // using OLD method of using name to find the control

    if ( document.register.user_username.value == "")
    {
    document.register.user_username.style.backgroundColor="red";
    isValid=false;
    }
    else{
    document.register.user_username.style.backgroundColor="white";
    }
    if ( document.register.user_password.value == "")
    {
    document.register.user_password.style.backgroundColor="red";
    isValid=false;
    }
    else{
    document.register.user_password.style.backgroundColor="white";
    }
    if ( document.register.user_password_confirm.value == "")
    {
    document.register.user_password_confirm.style.backgroundColor="red";
    isValid=false;
    }
    else{
    document.register.user_password_confirm.style.backgroundColor="white";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: where is the question? please be more specific

Comment: What went wrong with your method? Incidentally, I strongly recommend using server-side validation, either instead of or in addition to your javascript validation.

Comment: Sorry the question is for some reason the form still submits even though i don't put in a confirmed password. How can i validate this to make sure the password matches before submitting the form?

Comment: You should be checking this on the server as well. And not using alert() to display the error.

Comment: your function validate_reg(){... is not been closed

Comment: Is there an easier way to this validation than what i have shown?

Comment: what should be easier as if(pw1 != pw2)....?

Comment: yeah sorry i forgot to include the closing } in the question but that is not the fault

Comment: Sorry, this feels like re-inventing the wheel again http://parsleyjs.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where are you calling validatepw?

could add onchange="javascript:validatepw()" to both pwd fields

Comment: Hey this worked perfectly. I just added the onchange="validpw()" to the confirm password field. Thanks so much for the help